# Nested dictionaries in Pyparsing Parseresults

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using Pyparsing expression of the following type.

```
pp.SkipTo(common_cfg)('value 2') + common_cfg + pp.SkipTo(pp.LineEnd())
```

common_cfg is an expression that assigns 'value 1' to its result.

When I parse it asDict() I am getting nested Dictionaries. Why is it happening and how can I get around it? I just need an empty string in case of "value 2".

```
{'value 1': '52D4B6ED', 'value 2': ([''], {})}
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample that fully reproduces this, including an input string, definition of `common_cfg`, where `pp` comes from, and any other details needed to reproduce. A copy/paste of doing it on the REPL would probably be sufficient (if it isn't excessively long).

Comment: common_cfg is a bit involved as it is automatically generated by the code. Just wanted to know what is the meaning of nested dictionaries returned.

Comment: `common_cfg` being complicated is a good example of something you can *eliminate* when shortening your example. You could reproduce this just by picking a particular definition and putting that in the question. I think you'll find this elightening: http://sscce.org/. One of the big problems I had when originally reading your post is that I couldn't tell where you were getting your output from. The answer you accepted made several what happened to be a correct guesses; that you were looking at the `repr` is among them. Nonetheless, I'm glad you got your answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are seeing for "value 2" is not a nested dictionary.  You are getting a ParseResults object containing a single entry, an empty string. Since ParseResults have characteristics of both lists and dicts, its repr string shows both, first the list of parsed strings or objects, followed by a dict-like listing of any named results and their values.  Print out `type(result["value 2"])` to see this, or `result["value 2"].dump()`.

You may have some success by "ungrouping" the SkipTo results, using:

```
pp.ungroup(pp.SkipTo(common_cfg)('value 2'))
```

for the first term in your parser.